# Trying to write a function for interestCalculator but I keep getting errors

Tags: javascript

```
let data = 
        [
            {
                principal: 2500,
                time: 1.8
            },
            {
                principal: 1000,
                time: 5
            },
            {
                principal: 3000,
                time: 1
            },
            {
                principal: 2000,
                time: 3
            }
        ]
    console.log(data)

    function interestCalculator() {
        for (let i of data)

        if (data[i].principal>=2500 && data[i].time>1 && data[i].time<3){

        return "rate = 3"
        } else if (data[i].principal>=2500 && data[i].time>=3){

        return "rate = 4"
        } else if (data[i].principal<2500 && data[i].time<=1 ){

        return "rate = 2"
        } else {

        return "rate = 1"
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to write a function called "interestCalculator" that takes an array as a single argument and does the following:

Determine the rate applicable using the conditions:

- If the principal is greater than or equal to 2500 and the time is greater than 1 and less than 3, then rate = 3
- If the principal is greater than or equal to 2500 and the time is greater than or equal to 3, then rate = 4
- If the principal is less than 2500 or the time is less than or equal to 1, then rate = 2
- Otherwise, rate = 1;

But then I keep getting errors saying principal is undefined

Comment: Simply `i.principal` if you're using the `for..of` syntax. I wonder why typo questions are getting answers from even high rep users

Comment: are you missing the braces around your `for (let i of data) {}` or did you just not past correctly

Comment: Please start using `debugger` keyword asap.

Comment: try to use correct indentation/formatting, as it makes it easier to spot errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update loop statement. Use `in` instead of `of`

```
for (let i in data)
```

Comment: Incorrect, that is for iterating properties of an object

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected. But array indices are also technically object properties. Array is a child of Object,

Comment: FYC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

instead of data[i].principial, you should write like i.principial.
Here `i` is not index.
it is just an element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

when you loop over the array

```
for (let i of data) { ... }
```

`i` is already the object, so you need to use `i.principal` and `i.time`.

---

If you want instead to  access the `i`<sup>th</sup> element with `data[i]` then you need to loop the array with

```
 for (let i = 0, j = data.length; i++; i < j) { ... }
```

---

Finally as a side note it's worth to point that you have some `return` statements inside the loop, so the function will just check the first object in the array and will soon return, no matter how many elements may have `data`.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt have braces around your for loop and "for of" returns objects (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
function interestCalculator() {
    for (let obj of data) {   
        if (obj.principal>=2500 && obj.time>1 && obj.time<3){
           return "rate = 3"
        } 
        else if (obj.principal>=2500 && obj.time>=3){    
           return "rate = 4"
        } 
        else if (obj.principal<2500 && obj.time<=1 ){    
            return "rate = 2"
        } 

        return "rate = 1"            
    }
}
```

Comment: @RandWuch  also note in your code the last else in your code is redundant, as you are returning anyway, so i have removed in mine